# How to handle decryption of JSON payload

Tags: android, json, encryption, retrofit

I have a JSON payload being returned from a server but its encrypted.

Lets say the retrofit call looks like this:

```
@GET("/user/{id}/userprofile")  
void listUserProfile(@Path("id") int id, Callback<UserProfile> cb);
```

So how can i tell retrofit to first decrypt the payload and then afterwards use gson to convert the json to POJO (in this case UserProfile object) ? i am using okHttp for http client.

Comment: retrieve a `Response` object, read the content, decrypt it, then pass it to Gson for deserialization. But better yet, don't encrypt it. Use HTTPS to encrypt the whole communication and don't worry about it yourself

Comment: are you telling me not to use retrofit ?  how can i retrieve/intercept a Response object (ie. UserProfile) from retrofit ? The Callback is automatic. I am defining Callback<UserProfile> cb as the callback i dont see how i have control of the response object before its deserialized.

Comment: also, We are already using https but we MUST also use encryption on the payload for reasons. there is actually a challenge question in the payload thus further encryption is preferred. What would the retrofit code look like ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably writing an application `Interceptor` for your OkHttp client that will decrypt the body will do the trick:

```
public class DecryptedPayloadInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final DecryptionStrategy mDecryptionStrategy;

    public interface DecryptionStrategy {
        String decrypt(InputStream stream);
    }

    public DecryptedPayloadInterceptor(DecryptionStrategy mDecryptionStrategy) {
        this.mDecryptionStrategy = mDecryptionStrategy;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Response.Builder newResponse = response.newBuilder();
            String contentType = response.header("Content-Type");
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(contentType)) contentType = "application/json";
            InputStream cryptedStream = response.body().byteStream();
            String decrypted = null;
            if (mDecryptionStrategy != null) {
                decrypted = mDecryptionStrategy.decrypt(cryptedStream);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No decryption strategy!");
            }
            newResponse.body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), decrypted));
            return newResponse.build();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

If you are not using OkHttp, I'll gracefully remove the answer.

Comment: this is the way i was also thinking about. To intercept the response and then decrypt it. although i have not validated your code, taking it as psuedo the idea seems correct.